Create a new message with itemAttachment
Because Microsoft is phasing out EWS in a rather unusual fashion I am rewriting all of my code to use Microsoft Graph. Some things are quite easy and neat to rewrite. Copying a Message is not one of them. It has been a dreadful process of trial and error...
What I am trying to do:
I'm trying to create a new message in a users mailbox with a message as attachment. I don't want to actually send the message, I just want to simulate that the message was send/received. For this I am using POST /me/messages + some SingleValueExtendedProperties so the message is not a draft. This is different from all other questions where people want to use POST /me/sendMail like:

Create a message with itemAttachment
Send new message that includes a different message from user's inbox as attachment

My HTTP requests:
Creating the message (without an attachment) gives an HTTP 202. The message is shown in Outlook exactly as expected:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages HTTP/1.1
authorization: bearer {access_token}
content-type: application/json

{
  "createdDateTime": "2024-11-12T08:49:36Z",
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2024-11-12T08:49:36Z",
  "receivedDateTime": "2024-11-12T08:49:36Z",
  "sentDateTime": "2024-11-12T08:49:36Z",
  "hasAttachments": true,
  "subject": "Root e-mail",
  "body": "Root e-mail",
  "parentFolderId": "X",
  "sender": {
    "emailAddress": {
      "name": "Hielke",
      "address": "hielke@example.com"
    }
  },
  "from": {
    "emailAddress": {
      "name": "Hielke",
      "address": "hielke@example.com"
    }
  },
  "toRecipients": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "name": "Hielke",
        "address": "hielke@example.com"
      }
    }
  ],
  "SingleValueExtendedProperties": [
    {
      "Id": "Integer 0x0E07",
      "Value": "1"
    },
    {
      "Id": "SystemTime 0x0039",
      "Value": "2024-11-12T08:49:36Z"
    },
    {
      "Id": "SystemTime 0x0E06",
      "Value": "2024-11-12T08:49:36Z"
    }
  ]
}

When adding an Attachment I am using the content of /me/messages/Y. When POSTing the follow request it returns an HTTP 202, so it works, but creates it as a draft unlike the root message.
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/X/attachments HTTP/1.1
authorization: bearer {access_token}
content-type: application/json

{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.itemAttachment",
    "name": "Y",
    "item": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.message",
        "@odata.etag": "Y",
        "id": "Y",
        "createdDateTime": "2024-11-08T12:38:56Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2024-11-08T12:38:59Z",
        "changeKey": "Y",
        "categories": [],
        "receivedDateTime": "2024-11-08T12:38:57Z",
        "sentDateTime": "2024-11-08T12:38:53Z",
        "hasAttachments": true,
        "internetMessageId": "Y",
        "subject": "E-mail as attachment",
        "importance": "normal",
        "parentFolderId": "Y",
        "conversationId": "Y",
        "conversationIndex": "Y",
        "isDeliveryReceiptRequested": false,
        "isReadReceiptRequested": false,
        "isRead": true,
        "isDraft": false,
        "webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=X&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem",
        "inferenceClassification": "focused",
        "body": {
            "contentType": "html",
            "content": "E-mail as attachment"
        },
        "sender": {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "Hielke",
                "address": "hielke@example.com"
            }
        },
        "from": {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "Hielke",
                "address": "hielke@example.com"
            }
        },
        "toRecipients": [
            {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "Hielke",
                    "address": "hielke@example.com"
                }
            }
        ],
        "ccRecipients": [],
        "bccRecipients": [],
        "replyTo": [],
        "flag": {
            "flagStatus": "notFlagged"
        },
        "SingleValueExtendedProperties": [
            {
                "Id": "Integer 0x0E07",
                "Value": "1"
            },
            {
                "Id": "SystemTime 0x0039",
                "Value": "2024-11-08T12:38:57Z"
            },
            {
                "Id": "SystemTime 0x0E06",
                "Value": "2024-11-08T12:38:57Z"
            }
        ]
    }
}

Creating a message with a FileAttachment directly works as expected. Creating a message with an ItemAttachment directly works (HTTP 202), but also created the attachment is a draft.
And then I haven't even tried creating an ItemAttachment with an ItemAttachment (inception)...
What I have tried:

Adding the SingleValueExtendedProperties to the Item of ItemAttachment as well does not make the ItemAttachment a non-draft.
Passing ALL properties of the Message I want to attach does not make the ItemAttachment a non-draft. It does not show the any of the timestamps of the Message.


Could you share how you are adding an item attachment? What error does the Graph API return?

I've updated the question.
